# delete only japanese numbers laravel

Tags: php, laravel, string

I have this string

```
名古屋市北区,大曽根３丁目 １３-２V-
```

in UFT-8 encode, I want to replace (or delete) only japanese numbers with latin numbers

expected result

```
名古屋市北区,大曽根3丁目 12-2V-
```

or

```
名古屋市北区,大曽根丁目 -V-
```

how can I do it in laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex :

```
$words = '名古屋市北区,大曽根３丁目 １３-２V-';
$words = preg_replace('/\d+/u', '', $words);

dd($words);
```

Output :

```
"名古屋市北区,大曽根丁目 -V-"
```

Explain :

`\d+`

- `\d` matches a digit zero through nine in any script except ideographic scripts
- `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Global pattern flags

- `u` modifier: `unicode`. Pattern strings are treated as `UTF-16`. Also causes escape sequences to match unicode characters

---

By the way, it works perfectly for :

- [Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) (`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`)
- [Brahmi numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmi_numerals) (`, , , , , , , , ,` )
- [Devanagari numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari) (`०, १, २, ३, ४, ५, ६, ७, ८, ९`)
- [Gujarati numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gujarati_script) (`૦, ૧, ૨, ૩, ૪, ૫, ૬, ૭, ૮, ૯`)
- [Gurmukhi numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gurmukhi) (`੦, ੧, ੨, ੩, ੪, ੫, ੬, ੭, ੮, ੯`)
- [Bengali numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assamese_alphabet) (`০, ১, ২, ৩, ৪, ৫, ৬, ৭, ৮, ৯`)
- [Kannada numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannada_script) (`೦, ೧, ೨, ೩, ೪, ೫, ೬, ೭, ೮, ೯`)
- [Odia numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odia_script) (`୦, ୧, ୨, ୩, ୪, ୫, ୬, ୭, ୮, ୯`)
- [Malayalam numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malayalam_script) (`൦, ൧, ൨, ൩, ൪, ൫, ൬, ൭, ൮, ൯`)
- [Tamil numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_script) (`௦, ௧, ௨, ௩, ௪, ௫, ௬, ௭, ௮, ௯`)
- [Telugu numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telugu_script) (`౦, ౧, ౨, ౩, ౪, ౫, ౬, ౭, ౮, ౯`)
- [Burmese numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burmese_script) (`၀, ၁, ၂, ၃, ၄, ၅, ၆, ၇, ၈, ၉`)
- [Tibetan numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibetan_script) (`༠, ༡, ༢, ༣, ༤, ༥, ༦, ༧, ༨, ༩`)
- [Mongolian numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian_script) (`᠐, ᠑, ᠒, ᠓, ᠔, ᠕, ᠖, ᠗, ᠘, ᠙`)
- [Sinhala numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinhala_script) (`෦, ෧, ෨, ෩, ෪, ෫, ෬, ෭, ෮, ෯`)
- [Khmer numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khmer_script) (`០, ១, ២, ៣, ៤, ៥, ៦, ៧, ៨, ៩`)
- [Thai numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_script) (`០, ១, ២, ៣, ៤, ៥, ៦, ៧, ៨, ៩`)
- [Lao numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lao_script) (`໐, ໑, ໒, ໓, ໔, ໕, ໖, ໗, ໘, ໙`)
- [Javanese numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javanese_script) (`꧐, ꧑, ꧒, ꧓, ꧔, ꧕, ꧖, ꧗, ꧘, ꧙`)
- [Eastern Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) (Arabic, Persian / Dari / Pashto, Urdu / Shahmukhi) (`٠, ١, ٢, ٣, ٤, ٥, ٦, ٧, ٨, ٩`)